# Iterating over a vector inside a vector

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am trying to iterate over this vector to figure out if a function I have that checks for names in a vector is working.

```
  typedef struct device_t
    {
        string id;
        vector<string> capabilities;
    } Device;


vector<Device> devices = {
  { .id = "Television", .capabilities = { "audio", "channel" } },
  { .id = "Smart thermostat", .capabilities = { "temperature" } },
  { .id = "Stereo system", .capabilities = { "audio", "music" } },
  { .id = "Kitchen sink", .capabilities = { } },
  { .id = "Paper shredder", .capabilities = { "shredding" } }
};

 vector<Device>::iterator it;

    for (it = devicecheck.begin(); it != devicecheck.end(); it++) {
        std::cout<< *it;
    }
```

However I have no idea as to reach the `{.id}` part inside of the vector `devices`.  any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it->capabilities` is the `std::vector<std::string> capabilities` of the `Device` pointed to by the current iterator `it`. To iterate over `capabilities` you'd do:

```
for (it = devicecheck.begin(); it != devicecheck.end(); it++) {
    for (auto it2 = it->capabilities.begin(); it2 != it->capabilities.end(); it2++)
    {
        std::cout << *it2 << " "; 
    }
}
```

If you don't necessarily need access to the iterators themselves (but just the underlying object) consider the range-based for loop syntax:

```
for (auto& device : devicecheck)
{
    for (auto& capability : device.capabilities)
    {
        std::cout << capability << " ";
    }
}
```